# oracle update collection

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have two user defined collection types. The first type has the columns:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TYPE collection_1 as OBJECT
(
currency_code   varchar2(30),
amount   number
)
```

I have populated this collection inside a stored procedure using oracle bulk collect.So now let us say, the collection has values like this:

```
currency_code     amount
CAD               100
USD               50
CAD                120
USD               30
```

Now I want perform some aggregate functions on this collection and populate another collection that will store the total amount per currency. So I defined another collection like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TYPE collection_2 as OBJECT
(
currency_code   varchar2(30),
total_amount   number
)
```

And initialized it like this:

```
currency_code    total_amount
CAD               0
USD               0
GBP               0
```

Now I want to iterate over the collection_1 and populate collection_2 so that collection_2 reads like this:

```
currency_code    total_amount
CAD               220              --i.e.100+120
USD               80
GBP               0
```

How can I do it?

Comment: If You want to aggregate collection_1 then why to iterate over it when populating collection_2? Can't You just populate collection_2 with the aggregated collection_1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be something like this.

```
declare
    TYPE t_coll_1 is TABLE OF collection_1;
    v_coll_1    t_coll_1;

    TYPE t_coll_2 is TABLE OF collection_2;
    v_coll_2          t_coll_2;

begin
    /* populate v_coll_1 */
    /* populate v_coll_2 */

    for i in v_coll_2.first.. v_coll_2.last
    loop
       for j in v_coll_1.first.. v_coll_1.last
       loop
          if v_coll_2(i).currency_code = v_coll_1(j).currency_code
          then
              v_coll_2(i).total_amount := v_coll_2(i).total_amount + v_coll_1(j).total_amount;
          end if;
       end loop;
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you. i arrived at the exact solution. thanks for the code sample